# DecorView not drawing over SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-view

I have an application that uses `SurfaceView` do draw content. I wanted to add nice [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) library to my application which uses `getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(...)` to draw itself on top of other views and decorations. But in my case it does not draw over my `SurfaceView` (if I remove it from layout, everything works perfect).

Is it a limitation of Android architecture, or I can tune something in my `SurfaceView` or fix something in ShowcaseView library?

**Update**

If I call `mySurfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` just before creating `ShowcaseView` everything works perfect too (except that my main view area is black).

**Update 2**

I've read about Z-indexes of `SurfaceView` in documentation. I do not touch them in my code.

Comment: Try to add `setWillNotDraw(false)` after calling super in the constructor of your SurfaceView. Oh and try to add your SurfaceView to a container (`RelativeLayout`)

Comment: Try to call in your `onResume` `getWindow().getDecorView()).requestTransparentRegion(mySurfaceView);`

Comment: Thanks, `setWillNotDraw(false)` has helped. Can you formalize this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***SOLUTION***

Add `setWillNotDraw(false)` after calling  the super constructor of your SurfaceView.

---

*Other hints **regarding surfaceview***

*It might be helpful to*

1. *add the SurfaceView to a Container -e.g. RelativeLayout*
2. *call `getWindow().getDecorView()).requestTransparentRegion(mySurfaceView);` after making your view visible*